# "Extra data after the contents of the last column" while trying to import a csv file into postgresql (using pgadmin)

Tags: database, postgresql, csv

I am trying in import dataset from kaglle, but get error from title. My both table in SQL and CSV file have 16 columns, so i don't get the point of error. It's the same and match, isn't it?

My command:

```
COPY games(Name, Platform, Year_of_Release, Genre, Publisher, NA_Sales, EU_Sales, JP_Sales, Other_Sales, Global_Sales, Critic_Score, Critic_Count, User_Score, User_Count, Developer, Rating)
FROM 'E:\CSV\games.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
```

Command that I used to create table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.games
(
    name character varying,
    platform character varying,
    year_of_release integer,
    genre character varying,
  Publisher character varying,
  NA_Sales numeric,
  eu_Sales numeric,
  jp_Sales numeric,
  Other_Sales numeric,
  Global_Sales numeric,
  Critic_Score integer,
  Critic_Count integer,
  User_Score numeric,
  User_Count integer,
  developer character varying,
  Rating character varying
);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.games
    OWNER to postgres;
```

And the error:

> ERROR: extra data after the contents of the last column
> CONTEXT: COPY games, line 2: "Wii Sports,Wii,2006,Sports,Nintendo,41.36,28.96,3.77,8.45,82.53,76,51,8,322,Nintendo,E,"
>
> ERROR: extra data after last column contents
> SQL state: 22P04

The dataset: [https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rush4ratio/video-game-sales-with-ratings](https://stackoverflow.com)

I need to import CSV file into postgresql for some practice. I guess it's pretty easy problem but google and chatgtp don't help me much

Comment: 'chatgtp don't help me much' - oh well,, anyway removed mysql tag

Comment: The issue is `...E,`. The trailing `,` implies another column.

Comment: The error message is pretty on the nose. You have 17 columns on account of that trailing comma. I don't want to download that file on the machine I'm on, but the first thing to check is whether that dangling comma actually exists in the original csv. Might have to do some cleanup of the file.

Comment: I am not seeing the trailing `,` in the original data. Did you do some something with the CSV before you did the `COPY`?

Comment: Just realized you are using `pgAdmin` to do this. I seem to recall `pgAdmin` has issues using `COPY` in the query tool. I would suggest using either the `pgAdmin` [Import/Export dialog](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/8.0/import_export_data.html) or use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Comment: I got this to work using `psql` and its meta-command `\copy games from '/home/aklaver/test/videogame_data/Video_Games_Sales_as_at_22_Dec_2016.csv' with csv header` with result `COPY 16719`. I did change the `numeric` and `integer` columns to `varchar` as there where non-numeric/integer values in the CSV data for those columns.